# Reconstructing a Database by Parsing Data from a Text File

Tags: python, database, parsing, database-design

O'Reilly Publications - Programming Python 
Page - 17 , Step - 2:Storing Records Persistently

Well..I gotta reconstruct a database by parsing data from a text file and I'm using the code below.
The "storeDbase()" method made total sense and I was able to effectively implement it. However I got totally stumped while trying to get the "loadDbase()" function working. It isn't making any sense and I'd be really glad if someone could explain it to me.

Thank You.

The Text File.."people-file.txt"

```
Bob
AGE=> 42
JOB=> Developer
PAY=> 30000
NAME=> Bob Smith
endrec.
Steve
AGE=> 42
JOB=> Brewer
PAY=> 20000
NAME=> Bob Smith
endrec.
Sue
AGE=> 31
JOB=> Coder
PAY=> 50000
NAME=> Sue Willy
endrec.
Tom<br>
AGE=> 57
JOB=> Prez
PAY=> 90000
NAME=> Tom Heathern
endrec.
enddb.
```

*Database is a dictionary from the DatabaseInfo module.

```
    dbfilename = 'people-file.txt'
    ENDDB  = 'enddb.'
    ENDREC = 'endrec.'
    RECSEP = '=>'

    def storeDbase(db, dbfilename=dbfilename):
        "formatted dump of database to flat file"
        dbfile = open(dbfilename, 'w')
        for key in db:
            print(key, file=dbfile)
            print(key)
            for (name, value) in db[key].items():
                #print (value , "**")
                print(name + RECSEP , value, file=dbfile)
                print(name + RECSEP + repr(value))
            print(ENDREC, file=dbfile)
            print(ENDREC)
        print(ENDDB, file=dbfile)
        print(ENDDB)
        dbfile.close()

    def loadDbase(dbfilename=dbfilename):
        "parse data to reconstruct database"
        dbfile = open(dbfilename)
        import sys
        sys.stdin = dbfile
        db = {}
        key = input()
        while key != ENDDB:
            rec = {}
            field = input()
            while field != ENDREC:
                name, value = field.split(RECSEP)
                rec[name] = eval(value)
                field = input()
            db[key] = rec
            key = input()
        return db

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        from DatabaseInfo import Database
        storeDbase(Database)
```

Comment: The code seams correct, if you don't understand, take a paper sheet, a pen and try to see what the variables `key` and `rec` holds at every step of the algorithm on your example. If functions such as `input()` make you hesitate, open a python terminal and play with them, read their doc, and the algorithm should be clear...

Comment: I had no qualms whatsoever regarding the exactitude of the code..and I have a fair idea how the function works..and as stated above..it isn't making sense..so..instead being snobbish..help me out.

Comment: Posted the algorithm as pseudo code, but you should really try to take a pen and a paper and write yourself the state of the variable at each step of the execution. It is not `snobbish` but the way I do when facing an algorithm that I don't understand...

Answer (score 1):

```
while key != ENDDB:
    rec = {}
    field = input()
    while field != ENDREC:
        name, value = field.split(RECSEP)
        rec[name] = eval(value)
        field = input()
    db[key] = rec
    key = input()
```

Could be interpreted as :

```
key := the first line
while the key isn't the end of the database
  | rec := initialize a new reccord
  | field := read the next line
  | while the field isnt the end of the reccord
  |   | key, value := splitting the field (and so the line)
  |   | add to the reccord the association key,value : reccord of key := value
  |   L field := next line
  L as we are here, we reached the end of the reccord, so save the reccord : database of key := reccord
as we are here, we reached the end of database line, so return the builded database
```

the first `while` loop iterate over the record until the end of the file is reached. Each record analysis is delegated to the second loop that iterate over the lines until the end of the record is reached.

Comment: But what is up with.. sys.stdin = dbfile ??

Comment: Never used this syntax but by looking the code I understand this : `input()` read the next entry on the standard input (`sys.stdin`). On this piece of code it redirect the standard input on the file so each time it call `input()` it get the next file's line. That's why I said play with the functions in a terminal and read the doc... One can certainly obtain the same result by calling `dbfille.nextline()`, but this is another question.